# define the range of Longitude from 0-360 in the World plot from CountryData

Tags: graphics, curated-data

How can I change the Longitude range to 0-360 in the such plots?

```
Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.2],AbsoluteThickness[1.5],
  CountryData[
    "World", {"SchematicPolygon",{"Equirectangular",{0,180}}}
  ]/.Polygon->Line},
  Frame->True,ImageSize->200]
```

[image: World map]

Thanks

Comment: I don't think longitude goes above +/- 180, though...

Comment: @cormullion Among many examples of longitude extending beyond the $[-180,180]$ range, NASA's recent Cassini mission [mapped Titan](http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/images/moons/images/PIA14908-br500.jpg) between 0 and 360 degrees longitude.  In principle there's no limit to longitude; for instance, to describe a spiraling track around the earth, one might prefer to use as many multiples of 360 degrees as there are windings of the spiral (in order to maintain a local continuity of the longitude coordinate).

Comment: @whuber well, I learn something every day!

Comment: It is common to use longitude between 0 and 360 in climate science (although 180W-180E is more common). In Mathematica, the command Longitude is also defined between -180 and 360.

Answer (score 3):

Simply like this:

```
map = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.2], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
    CountryData[
      "World", {"SchematicPolygon", {"Equirectangular", {0, 
         180}}}] /. Polygon -> Line}, Frame -> True];

Show[map, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {Transpose[{Range[13]*30 - 210, Range[13]*30 - 30}], 
    None}}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

```
Show[map, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {Transpose[{Range[13]*30 - 210, 
      RotateLeft[Range[13]*30 - 30, 7] /. x_ /; x > 180 :> x - 30}], 
    None}}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

In answer to comment:-

```
map = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.2], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
    CountryData[
      "World", {"SchematicPolygon", {"Equirectangular", {0, 
         180}}}] /. Polygon -> Line}, Frame -> True];

linepos = First[Position[map, Line]];
line = Extract[map, Most[linepos]];
newline = line /. {a_Real, b_} :> {a + 180, b};
map2 = ReplacePart[map, Most[linepos] -> newline];

p2 = ListContourPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
   Contours -> 15, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   DataRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 90}}];

Show[p2, map2, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a great help.

Comment: Now I face with another problem.When I try the following, I do not get the two plots on each other with the newly defined range for longitude.For example: `p2 = ListContourPlot[
  Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], Contours -> 15,
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  DataRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 90}}] ;        Show[p1, map, ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {Transpose[{Range[13]*30 - 210, Range[13]*30 - 30}], 
    None}}, ImageSize -> 400]`

Comment: many thanks again