# Cannot combine GeoPosition polygons in version 10.4

Tags: graphics, polygons, geography

I was using with Mathematica 10 for plotting different kinds of maps the function PolygonCombine. It seems that this fucntion has disappeared with the version 10.4?
Here is a classical example for the use of this function:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

world = CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ 
    CountryData["Continents"] // Flatten;

worldplot = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], PolygonCombine@world} /. 
   Polygon -> Line, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Longitude", "Latitude"}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

How I could do the same thing now by replacing the function PolygonCombine without changing all my programs?
Thank you.

---

Thank you for your help.
But now I have detected another problem: I cannot remove Antartica continents like I was doing previously?

See the following example:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

world = CountryData[#,"FullPolygon"] & /@ 
    Cases[CountryData["Continents"], Except["Antarctica"]] // Flatten;

worldplot = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Polygon[GeoPosition[#]] & @@ (PolygonCombine[
       Polygon @@@ world[[All, 1]]])} /. Polygon -> Line, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Longitude", "Latitude"}, 
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `RegionPlot[world] /. Polygon->Line` ?

Comment: What exactly should it do?  If I just remove the `PolygonCombine@` from your code, I get [this]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/PY6Ff.png) - what do you want that is different from that?

Comment: To help you find where it is now: ``?*`*PolygonCombine``

Comment: @JasonB We are wrong, the `PolygonCombine` should actually remove the internal borders ! See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18387/19960)

Comment: @SquareOne - Yeah, I actually just installed version 9 so I could check that out.  I was going to see if you could create a `BoundaryMeshRegion` out of it and go from there.  I started with `DiscretizeGraphics@Graphics@world` - and then my computer started thinking so hard it was unresponsive and I had to restart.  So, um, don't try that

Comment: @SquareOne - I don't have version 10.4, but in 10.3 the OP's code above does not work, but I don't think it has to do with `PolygonCombine`, but rather with the representation of the polygons.  If you have version 10.4, try replacing the definition of `world` above with `world = << "https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl5w33qr9ppfedi/world.txt?dl=1";` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @JasonB Seems you are right, the OP example works in 10.3.1 and 10.4 when I replace it with your `world`. So the `Polygon[GeoPosition[...]]` form seems not to work anymore in `PolygonCombine` ?

Comment: Yeah, giving a workaround now.

Comment: @F.Aitken, generally, if you have a new question then you should post it as such.  To add new parts to a question that has been answered is known as "Moving the goalposts"  :-)

Comment: But to answer your new question, the type of object returned by `CountryData` has changed in version 10.  You can get what you want by applying `CanonicalName` like in [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw/BbnBzrME)

Answer (score 4):

So when I tried the code from the OP in version 10.3, I get the error message

> `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine `` is not a Graphics primitive or
>   directive.

while in version 9 it returns this image

[image]

So it is natural to assume that the undocumented function is the culprit, and WRI just removed it without saying anything, which is their prerogative. But I think the issue is with the `GeoPosition` polygons instead.

Let's look at the representation of the polygons in version 10.3,

```
CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]
```

[image]

and compare it to the same thing in version 9,

```
CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]
(* Polygon[{{{7.24916, 53.3298}, {6.99916, 53.359}, ...
            .... {8.59249, 54.5073}}}] *)
```

So now there is some sort of internal gray box between us and the polygon coordinates, and it seems to be confusing the `PolygonCombine` function.  (Thanks to SquareOne for making this easier)  You can convert it to a normal `Polygon` via

```
Polygon @@ First@CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]
(* Polygon[{{{53.3298, 7.24916}, {53.359, 6.99916},
            ......{54.5073, 8.59249}}}] *)
```

But the x and y coordinates have been reversed.  For some reason, `GeoPosition` seems to tell `Polygon` to swap the coordinates.  For this I'll `Map` `Reverse` to the second-deepest level of the polygon.

```
Polygon @@ First@CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"] // 
  Map[Reverse, #, {-2}] & // Graphics
```

[image]

Of course you get the exact same output if you use `CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]`, but it is **not** a normal polygon.  Just try `Cases[CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"] // Graphics, Polygon[_]]` to see this.

It's pretty easy to apply this to the `world` list, just adding one line to the code in the OP

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

world = CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ CountryData["Continents"] //
    Flatten;
world = Map[Reverse, #, {-2}] &@*Polygon @@@ world[[All, 1]];

worldplot = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], PolygonCombine@world} /. 
   Polygon -> Line, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Longitude", "Latitude"}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

SquareOne pointed out that you could skip the `Map` step and use the fact that `GeoPosition` inverts the coordinates to your advantage by replacing `PolygonCombine@world` with `Polygon[GeoPosition[#]] & @@ (PolygonCombine[ Polygon @@@ world[[All, 1]]])`  This does result in a slightly shorter code (by 6 bytes  :-P), but I prefer the `Map` method for clarity and because it seems to run faster without the extra step of reusing `GeoPosition`.

To get the map without Antarctica (who needs it!!), we use this

```
world = CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ 
    Cases[CountryData["Continents"], 
     Except[EntityClass["Country", "Antarctica"]]] // Flatten;

world = Map[Reverse, #, {-2}] &@*Polygon @@@ world[[All, 1]];

worldplot = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], PolygonCombine@world} /. 
   Polygon -> Line, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Longitude", "Latitude"}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: It wasn't removed. I gave a hint in the comments on how to find its current context.

Comment: Right, but it can actually still be found via the older context as well (er, almost).  It's odd, but by loading `Graphics\`Mesh\`MeshInit[];` you can call it directly, or you can call it via `Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`PolygonCombine` which is what you get when you do your search

Comment: But oddly enough, you can't call it like you used to, with `Graphics\`Mesh\`PolygonCombine`

Comment: But this is beside the point, since the real issue at hand is "What have they done with geographical polygons and why did they do it?"

Comment: @JasonB What a mess ... It means that when `Polygon` is applied to `GeoPosition` it knows that it has to reverse the coordinates ... Anyway, I think I have something shorter : in th OP's code just replace `PolygonCombine[world]` with `Polygon[GeoPosition[#]] & @@ (PolygonCombine[
   Polygon @@@ world[[All, 1]]])`

Comment: @SquareOne So there you are using `GeoPosition` to swap the coordinates?  That may be shorter than mapping `Reverse`, but I like the latter for some reason.  I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of just using `Apply` to get rid of `GeoPosition` in the first place though, that bit about `FullForm` is ridiculous. Thanks for the help