# How to test if a GeoPosition is inside a geographic Polygon?

Tags: geography, expression-test, polygons

I have tried the following:

```
usentity = Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"];
uspoly = usentity["Polygon"];
stdpoly = uspoly /. GeoPosition -> Identity;
RegionQ[stdpoly]
```

[1] True

```
RegionMember[stdpoly, {35, -90}]
```

returns unevaluated.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: You're looking for [`GeoWithinQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoWithinQ.html).

Comment: @rcollyer - perfect, just what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the structure of the `Polygon`, it seems there is an extra level of `{}` that needs to be removed

```
Short@stdpoly
(* Polygon[{{{49.0021,-122.758},<<2620>>}}] *)
```

So you can use `FlattenAt` to remove that layer of brackets,

```
stdpoly2=FlattenAt[stdpoly,{1,1}];
Short@stdpoly
(* Polygon[{{{49.0021,-122.758},<<2620>>}}] *)
```

The polygons appear the same

```
RegionPlot /@ {stdpoly, stdpoly2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and now you can use `RegionMember` all you like

```
RegionMember[stdpoly2, {35, -90}]
(* True *)
```

There is also the fact that for some reason, geographic polygons have their coordinates reversed, as I learned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110928/9490).  This is what I did there,

```
stdpoly = Polygon @@ First@First@uspoly // Map[Reverse, #, {-2}] &;
Graphics@stdpoly
RegionMember[stdpoly, {-90, 35}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* True  *)
```

As rcollyer points out, you can use the built-in [`GeoWithinQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoWithinQ.html) to test this as well,

```
GeoWithinQ[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], GeoPosition[{35, -90}]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: JasonB, thanks!  I just discovered that myself also.