# RegionIntersection and area on GeoPosition polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, geography

I am trying to write a simple procedure to find the percentage of a large property falls in each surrounding ZIP code. A problem that I am encountering is the fact that RegionIntegration[] and Area[] does not seem to work with regions that contain GeoPosition values.

```
tmp = Polygon[GeoPosition[{{{39.191046`, -78.198858`}, {39.191161`, -78.196945`}, {39.204733`, -78.187792`}, {39.198913`, -78.163766`}}}]];
tmp2 = Polygon[{{{39.191046`, -78.198858`}, {39.191161`, -78.196945`}, {39.204733`, -78.187792`}, {39.198913`, -78.163766`}}}];

Area[tmp] (*Area::reg: "Polygon[GeoPosition[{{{39.191,-78.1989},{39.1912,-78.1969},{39.2047,-78.1878},{39.1989,-78.1638}}}]] is not a correctly specified region." *)
Area[tmp2] (*.000184847*) (* I know that this number is meaningless without units but I am using it to get the percentage of an region is in the intersection of another region so it can be used in this case.*)
```

I know that for this example I could simply remove the tag with:

```
tmp[[1]] = tmp[[1]][[1]]
```

This encounters problems when there is a filled curve containing multiple lines. It should be fairly straight forwards to handle this issue but I can't help but think that I must be missing something.

Does anyone have any guidance? I am new to mathematica. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Ran into this before [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110920/9490).  To turn `GeoGraphics` polygon into a regular polygon, this works:  `tmp2 = Polygon @@ First[tmp]; Area@tmp2`

Comment: Or something like `tmp2 = tmp /. GeoPosition -> Sequence`, creates a regular polygon out of the geo-polygon

Comment: But then there's always the `GeoArea` function......  `GeoArea @ tmp` gives an answer